# How to add foreign key to entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception.

I'm using EF Code first and I'm getting error above when I trying do this:

```
public ActionResult CreateTransaction(TransactionViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (model.MemberId != 0 && model.SubcategoryId != 0 & model.CategoryId != 0)
            {
                Transaction t = new Transaction();
                t.Amount = model.Amount;
                t.Comment = model.Comment;
                t.Date = DateTime.Now;
                t.TransactionSubcategory = db.Subcategories.Find(model.SubcategoryId);//and i have error in this line
                //i tried also this code below but it's the same error
                //db.Subcategories.Find(model.SubcategoryId).Transactions.Add(t);

                db.Members.Find(model.MemberId).Transactions.Add(t);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("CreateTransaction") ;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return RedirectToAction("CreateTransaction");
        }
    }
```

And there is my model

```
public class Subcategory
{
    public Subcategory()
    {
        IsGlobal = false;
        Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TransactionType TypeOfTransaction { get; set; }

    public Category OwnerCategory { get; set; }

    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public Subcategory TransactionSubcategory { get; set; }

    public Member OwnerMember { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know why thats happen because in database in Transaction table i see there is column with FK.
If you need there is rest of the model

```
public class Budget
{
    public Budget()
    {
        Members = new List<Member>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string BudgetName { get; set; }

    public string OwnerName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        IsGlobal = false;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }

    public Budget OwnerBudget { get; set; }

    public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    }

    public Budget OwnerBudget { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public enum TransactionType
{
    Income,
    Expenditure
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
public int TransactionSubcategoryId { get; set; }
public int OwnerMemberId { get; set; }
```

In your Transaction class.

Comment: Now I get this: `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Transactions_dbo.Categories_TransactionCategory_Id". The conflict occurred in database "HomeBudgetMVC5", table "dbo.Categories", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: @user3763726 It seems that you're trying to update Transaction with CategoryId = 0, which doesn't exist in your database. But I don't see Category relation in Transaction class. Do you have FK on CategoryId in Transation table?

Comment: No. In Transaction table is FK on SubcategoryId. On begin of action is line `if (model.MemberId != 0 && model.SubcategoryId != 0 & model.CategoryId != 0)` and in debug mode I see subcategoryId and categoryId have correct value.

Comment: Could you try to attach Subcategory to your Transaction by setting `TransactionSubcategoryId = db.Subcategories.Find(model.SubcategoryId).Id` ? Would do the same for MemberOwner.

Comment: Ok, fixed. I don't know why but there was FK on CategoryId in this table. Now everythings works fine. Thanks a lot, pozdrowionka :P